# Using preference _local in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nginx

I am currently tuning elasticsearch for search api. The specification are:

- 2 Nodes single cluster with single index on a VM (2 cores 2GB of RAM)
- 5 shards
- 1 replication
- load balanced using nginx

When I test it using Jmeter using Nginx it get throughput about ~220 req/s but when I specify the `?preference=_local` it can get to ~320 req/s. That's very good performance improvement. What I want to ask is :

1. What `?preference=_local` actually do and how it can improve the performance of the query?
2. What's the tradeoff of using `?preference=_local`?

Query :

```
{
"query": {
    "multi_match": {
        "query": "trump",
        "type": "most_fields",
        "operator": "and",
        "fields": ["title", "content"]
    }
},
"sort": {
    "published_at": {
        "order": "desc"
    },
    "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
    }
},
"from": 0,
"size": 20,
"min_score": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `_local` preference in this scenario is fine, since you have two nodes and one replica for your indices, which means each node has exactly the same data.

Preference `_local` will run the query you are sending to a node, **on that particular node's data**. If that node doesn't have the data that needs to be queried will send the requests to other nodes, as well.

Also, when querying an Elasticsearch cluster you need to send your search requests either via a client node, or via a load balancer or your code needs to target BOTH nodes. Basically you want all your nodes to perform the "gatherer" job. This is important because the node that receives the search request is the only who gathers the results from all other nodes, performs final searching and aggregations and send the results back to the user. So, the node that gets the request is the one who's doing more work.

In a two-node scenario with preference `_local` the queries load balancing is even more important because that node that gets the request always will perform all the work, the other one will be idle.

Comment: isn't that means if I use 5 nodes 5 shards with 1 replication and query using `_local` means I will only query in the 2/5 of the data?

Comment: First of all, your post is about 2 nodes, not 5. Secondly, if you'd have 5 nodes and 5 shards with 1 replica and using `_local` preference, Elasticsearch **will use the local shards on that node, but for those that are not there it will go "out" to other nodes and ask for the missing shards to be searched as well**.